# how to print the number of "and" words in a file for java

Tags: java

I am supposed to print the number of "and" words in a file, but I only know how to count the number of tokens and lines in a file. My program can only print the number of tokens in a file...

```java
import java.util.*;//for Scanner
import java.io.*;//for file
public class Hamlet2
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File filename = new File("hamlet.txt");
        Scanner read = new Scanner(filename);
        int andCount = 0;//to count word "and" 
        while(read.hasNext())//read words
        {
            String token = read.Next();
            andCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of "and" words: " + andCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read a line and test to see if the line contains " and "

Comment: This code should not compile, since `Scanner`s method you want to use is `next()`, not `Next()`. Beside that, you need to add some logic which compares the read `token` to your expected string and only then increases the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
public static int countWord(File fileName, String word) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        int count = 0;
        fileName = file.trim();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileName);
    
        while (scanner.hasNext())    {
            String nextWord = scanner.next().trim();
            if (nextWord.equals(word)) {
                ++count; 
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, sorry but I did not learn .trim yet. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: The trim method simply removed whitespaces in a given string